# Is it possible to create custom menus in WordPress with titles without links?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, menu

We are building a theme on WordPress 3.5.1 and we created two custom menus - one for the header and one for the footer. In the footer the titles are not linkable, therefore we created custom links with href "#" and then changed the href to "". The result are empty links with `<a>`. I know it's possible to change the cursor of these empty links with CSS:

```
.footer-content #sitemap ul.menu > li.menu-item > a {
    cursor: text;
}
```

and I also found out a way to remove these empty links with JavaScript and jQuery:

```
$('.footer-content #sitemap ul.menu > li.menu-item > a').each(function() {
    // If href is empty, remove <a> element.
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    var href_length = 0;
    if (!(typeof href === 'undefined')) {
        var href_length = href.length;
    }
    if (href_length === 0) {
        var contents = $(this).contents();
        $(this).replaceWith(contents);
    }
});
```

(the footer menu is inside the `.footer-content #sitemap` elements:

```
<div class="footer-content">
<div id="sitemap" class="not_mobile">
```

)

but is it possible to remove the empty `<a>` elements from the HTML without using JavaScript? The function that creates the footer menu is:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'footer_menu' ) ); ?>
```

Thanks,
Uri @ Initech.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found a solution. I searched and found out function `start_el(...)` on class `Walker_Nav_Menu`, then copied it and changed only the last part of it:

```
class themeslug_walker_nav_menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
    /**
     * @see Walker::start_el()
     * @since 3.0.0
     *
     * @param string $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
     * @param object $item Menu item data object.
     * @param int $depth Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
     * @param int $current_page Menu item ID.
     * @param object $args
     */
    function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
        $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

        $class_names = $value = '';

        $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
        $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;

        $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args ) );
        $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';

        $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'. $item->ID, $item, $args );
        $id = $id ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

        $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $value . $class_names .'>';

        $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';

        $item_output = $args->before;
        if (! empty( $item->url )) {
            $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
        }
        $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
        if (! empty( $item->url )) {
            $item_output .= '</a>';
        }
        $item_output .= $args->after;

        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
    }
}
```

Then I changed the call to `wp_nav_menu` on footer.php:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'footer_menu', 'walker' => new themeslug_walker_nav_menu ) ); ?>
```

It works and there are no `<a>` links when the href is empty (my changes are both ifs: `if (! empty( $item->url )) {`). Thanks to Mangesh Parte for the idea.

Uri.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It is possible. You can use the `walker`. Put the following class in your `functions.php` file

```
class themeslug_walker_nav_menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

    // add main/sub classes to li's and links
    function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth, $args ) {
        global $wp_query;
        $indent = ( $depth > 0 ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '' ); // code indent

        // depth dependent classes
        $depth_classes = array(
            ( $depth == 0 ? 'main-menu-item' : 'sub-menu-item' ),
            ( $depth >=2 ? 'sub-sub-menu-item' : '' ),
            ( $depth % 2 ? 'menu-item-odd' : 'menu-item-even' ),
            'menu-item-depth-' . $depth
        );
        $depth_class_names = esc_attr( implode( ' ', $depth_classes ) );

        // passed classes
        $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
        $class_names = esc_attr( implode( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item ) ) );

        // build html
        $output .= $indent . '<li id="nav-menu-item-'. $item->ID . '" class="' . $depth_class_names . ' ' . $class_names . '">';

        // link attributes
        $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ' class="menu-link ' . ( $depth > 0 ? 'sub-menu-link' : 'main-menu-link' ) . '"';

        if($depth == 0) {
            $item_output = sprintf( '%1$s%2$s%3$s%4$s%5$s',
                $args->before,
                $args->link_before,
                apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ),
                $args->link_after,
                $args->after
            );
        } else {
            $item_output = sprintf( '%1$s<a%2$s>%3$s%4$s%5$s</a>%6$s',
                $args->before,
                $attributes,
                $args->link_before,
                apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ),
                $args->link_after,
                $args->after
            );
        }
        // build html
        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
    }
}
```

and add this walker in your `wp_nav_menu` function
`<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'footer_menu', 'walker' => new themeslug_walker_nav_menu  ) ); ?>`

This will remove the anchor tag `<a>` from each menu item.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work. It added "000000000000000000" before the footer menu and removed *all* the <a> tags including where there is an href (all the submenu items are links, only the menu items are not links).

Comment: If this answer helped you the feel free to accept this as correct answer. ;)

Comment: Thank you, I think your code will work but I wanted to let the user decide where they want links and where just text without links, so I copied the function start_el() from the WordPress 3.5.1 code and just added ifs to not display the <a> tags where the href is empty. I will submit my code but I have to wait 8 hours because I'm a new user on this website with this e-mail address so I will submit my code later.